# Google Script Quotas - GmailApp.Search

Tags: google-apps-script

I've spliced together a script which runs on a 1-minute interval and does a look-up on a Google label:

```
var mailthreads = GmailApp.search('label:MYLABEL');
```

Initially, the script ran fine, however within a few days the script began to throw a variety of errors, such as:

- Service invoked too many times for one day: gmail
- Service using too much computer time for one day
- Service invoked too many times in a short time: gmail rateMax. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls.

I have checked [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) with no real explination on what could be causing the script to fail - it ran initially day-to-day without fail, and as the cycle for quotas is 24-hours I would imagine if one 24-hour cycle worked, why didn't the rest?

One theory I have is that the GmailApp.Search query counts each returned item under the label as a single read, and now that the label has grown in size I am reaching a quota limit on reads.  Is this how it works, and if not is there anything else I can check?